# How to route translated URLs to a module with nitrogen

Tags: internationalization, erlang, nitrogen

I used to develop in English, but this time, the webApp i'm building is only for people in my city, which is in France.

In nitrogen, when you call "/user/login", nitrogen calls user_login:main().
I would like nitrogen to call user_login:main() when the request is "/utilisateur/connexion".

I would like nitrogen to call ads_people:main() when the request is "/annonces/personnes", etc.

Is there a way to achieve that properly ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily by using Nitrogen's named_route_handler plugin. Steps are:

1. Insert following line before call to nitrogen:run():

   ```
   wf_handler:set_handler(named_route_handler, get_routes()).
   ```
2. Add get_routes/0 function:

   ```
   get_routes() -> [
       {"/utilisateur/connexion", user_login},
       {"/annonces/personnes", annonces_persons},
       etc...
   ].
   ```

   First element in a tuple is the path in URL and the second is the name of the corresponding module which will handle requests with such path.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proxy in front of Nitrogen like nginx to do that kind of URL rewriting.

Altrernatively, check out some of the documentation in src/handlers/route/named_route_handler.erl if you wanted to do it in pure nitrogen